# ASP.NET Set GridView Column max width size

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.NET C# on VS2005.

I have a GridView table with a column named `Description`, and since the input is always very long, the description is very long horizontally.

I would want the GridView to have a max width size for all columns.

I have tried many ways but none of them worked.

`ItemStyle-Width="50px"`,

`HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="50px"`,

`HeaderStyle-Width="50px"`,

`RowStyle-Width="50px"`,

`Width="50px"`

Below is a code snippet of my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="UserSelector" OnCheckedChanged="UserSelector_CheckedChanged" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Anyone know how to adjust the size of GridView columns based on my situation?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17457296/2415524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my code is this what you where thinking bout?

```
        <RowStyle Width="150px"/>
```

Remove all the stash

```
<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate> </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

and just use simple

```
<columns> </columns>
```

Here i how i think you code will look like AutoGenerateColumns="True" or false dont seeme to matter

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
         <Columns>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="UserSelector" OnCheckedChanged="UserSelector_CheckedChanged" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" runat="server" />
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle Width="150px"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @Thomos hi, your method can be applied to columns that are called out in the asp tab right? how do I implement the div to columns which are not in the asp tab, but will automatically show when the webpage is loaded, because I have set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true. If I set it to false, how do I create those columns in the asp tab?

Answer (score 8):

This is how I control the column width.

1.Add the CSS in the header.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .maxWidthGrid
    {
        max-width: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

2.Then use the CSS in necessary columns like this `ItemStyle-CssClass="maxWidthGrid"`

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="maxWidthGrid" DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Client Name"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ClientName" />
```

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to use '.maxWidthGrid td' to get this to stick, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected int widestData;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, 
    GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataRowView drv;
    drv = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if (drv != null)
      {
        String catName = drv[1].ToString();
        Response.Write(catName + "/");

        int catNameLen = catName.Length;
        if (catNameLen > widestData)
        {
          widestData = catNameLen;
          GridView1.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Width =
            widestData * 30;
          GridView1.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
        }

      }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    widestData = 0;
}
```

Check this [How to: Set GridView Web Server Control Column Width Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178296.aspx) for more detailed information.

if your gridview `autogeneratecolumns` property is set to false and you are creating `custom columns` then you can use `templatefileds` where you can implement `Table` and `Div` to control the width of the columns.