# Creating max width for GridView column and Wrap Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I cant figure out how to define the width of a particular column of a gridview. I am getting this result:

[image]

As you can see, I am getting substantial overflow. I would like to define a maximum width and wrap the test for this 5th column.

I have tried doing it programatically:

```
    GridView1.Columns[4].ItemStyle.Width = 300;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

And also in asp.net:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ItemStyle-Width="300px" />
```

or

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" HeaderStyle-Width="300px">
```

None of these attempts are having any effect.

Comment: You can use an item template, check this post out. [ASP.NET Setting width of DataBound column in GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266580/asp-net-setting-width-of-databound-column-in-gridview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following css class for grid:

```
.gridView
{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

and on the column use this css class:

```
.col
{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The text in the top last column has no spaces. This means that the last column will not wrap so the table will stretch. This is just like displaying a really big image that is too big for the container or page.

Comment: Right, I want to force wrapping in this circumstance.

Comment: Shashank Chaturvedi solution is correct. Learn something new everyday :)