# Resize GridView height?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to resize the GridView height every time an item is added or deleted? Let's say I have an initial height, and every time I add an item, I want to resize the gridview +20px or -20px if I delete an item.

Or even better, maybe an autoresize is available?

Comment: I think you added a Height attribute to the gridview so now its not autoresizing. Remove Height atrribute so it will autoresize

Comment: Yes, its inside a div which has got a height, the problem is that if I don't set a heigth to that div, then the gridview is not seen totally.
https://puu.sh/A74lw/1c308c06c3.png

Comment: so the issue is the div and not the gridview. What purpose does the div have and what css classes/styling

Comment: The purpose of the div is to set a Width, for some reason when setting a Width to the gridview, if I have a lot of columns, it exceed the width I had set.

Comment: if I dont use the div, the gridview width gets bigger than the one I set. Example, I set the gridview width to 300px and if I add various columns the width size increase.

Comment: multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265964/asp-net-set-gridview-column-max-width-size)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what helped me: style="overflow-x: auto;" and now the gridview mantains the correct size when adding or deleting items from it.